# Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':contacts_service' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':contacts_service'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\BLACK X.gradle\caches\jars-9\5504f2f5718c34379819066097c7f5fa\sdklib-27.0.1.jar.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':contacts_service' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':contacts_service' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Can someone tell me how to fix that? It's my first time editing an android project.